# Changing components language PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to change the language of some components from primefaces, like FILEUPLOAD component, it has buttons label as CHOOSE, CANCEL,UPLOAD, can i change this labels to my language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Choose** = `label="anyString"` **CANCEL** = `cancelLabel="anyString"` and **UPLOAD** = `uploadLabel="anyString"` then `<p:fileUpload cancelLabel="anyString" label="anyString" uploadLabel="anyString" />`